# Collect list result from multiple tornado coroutine calls

Tags: python, tornado

I have a Tornado coroutine to fetch data from server.

```
@coroutine
def fetch_detail_by_id(id: str) -> str:
   #blabla
```

and I want to create a coroutine that receives multiple arguments and call the coroutine above for each item in arguments and return list of the results

I tried this but it keep returning message `exception was never retrieved` What did I do wrong?

```
@coroutine
def fetch_details_by_ids(ids: list) -> list:
    results = []
    for id in ids:
        result = yield fetch_detail_by_id(id)
        results.append(result)
    return results
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback. A single line is not helpful to pin down the problem.

Comment: Yeray Diaz covers basic cases in [his article](https://hackernoon.com/asyncio-for-the-working-python-developer-5c468e6e2e8e). It might hint you what is wrong.